# How to creata a text input field in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object

I am building a system which takes user input from keyboard and does some animation. Couldn't find a tutorial explaining how to create something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires you to be comfortable with Python, but you could use the BGUI: https://github.com/Moguri/bgui

There is an example file that comes with the download that can help you get started.

Comment: I know python. But couldn't find any example script

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/Moguri/bgui/blob/master/examples/simple/blender_test.py